# Problem with space replaced by "â€‰"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a query to my database and i'm getting strange results like: 
`Intel Pentium III 1â€‰GHz or equivalent processor; 512â€‰MB of RAM; 70â€‰MB of free hard drive space; 1024â€‰xâ€‰768 screen resolution; Windows-compatible audio interface; Windows-compatible MIDI interface/keyboard`

Comment: Further information is required.  What is the database collation? what character encoding are you using?  What happens on your input forms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is U+2009 THIN SPACE encoded as UTF-8 being misinterpreted as CP1252. Fix your charset header.